# Handlebars {{#if}} {{elseif}} block helper not working

Tags: html, json, css, handlebars.js

I am parsing complex json using handlebars.js 
I want to display to name in different style if they matches a condition based on the json. 
So the json is as follows :

```
    "TradeLine":{  
             "TradeLine":{  
                "Mortgage Accounts":[  
                   {  
                      "SubscriberDisplayName":"SAVINGS AND LOAN COMPA",
                      "Evaluation":"N",
                      "EvaluationDesc":"Closer review is required",                      
                      "KOB":"Savings And Loan Companies",                     
                      "RevolvingOrInstallment":"I",
                      "RevolvingOrInstallmentDesc":"Installment",
                      "OpenOrClosed":"C",
                      "OpenOrClosedDesc":"Closed",
                      "Status":"05",
                     }
                     ]
             }
    }
```

I have followed the below links

[Block Helper Link referred](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html)

[Second referred Link](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582537-Using-Handlebars-for-Dynamic-Content)

What i want to do is if the Evaluation is "N" (Negative) then displayname should have "*" besides it name and should be colored RED else if it's "P" (Positive) it should be displayed as it is. 
How can i do that ? 
My HTML Code is like this

```
<thead class="thead-default">
                          <tr>
                            {{#if '"Evaluation" == "N"'}}
                            <th colspan="4" scope="colgroup"> {{SubscriberDisplayName}} * </th>
                            {{elseif '"Evaluation" == "P"'}}
                            <th colspan="4" scope="colgroup"> {{SubscriberDisplayName}}</th>
                            {{/if}}
                          </tr>
                          </thead>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Solved the above problem by below code:

```
{{#if_eq Evaluation "P"}}
    <th colspan="4" scope="colgroup"> {{SubscriberDisplayName}}</th>
{{else}}
    <th colspan="4" scope="colgroup" style="color:red"> {{SubscriberDisplayName}}*</th>
{{/if_eq}}
```